# Non-breaking hyphen displaying as an underscore under popular mobile browsers - what should I do as a web developer?

Tags: html

I needed a non-breaking hyphen in a webpage, so I used it:

```
foo&#8209;bar
```

Everything worked ok when I tested it on my laptop, on both Firefox and Chromium. When the site was ready, I finally tested it on a mobile phone.

It came out that the Android browsers based on Chromium - the default Samsung Marshmallow browser and CyanogenMod's Gello both display the non-breaking hyphen as an underscore instead.

How should I handle this? Bug reports in such big projects take forever until resolved and I want my webpage to display properly on mobiles.

Comment: %20 you forgot the %

Comment: @mlegg: no, it should be human-readable 20. I'll change it to `foo` & `bar` so that no doubts arise

Comment: Stab in the dark, but have you tried changing the font?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this as well.  One thing I discovered is that it was unique to the font we are using.  The non-breaking hyphen would get converted to an underscore on Android if we were using the freight-text-pro font, but not another font.  You can try switching fonts or try `<span style="white-space: nowrap;">hyphenated-word</span>` and use a regular hyphen instead.

Comment: This help figure it out for us. Alternately, we changed the font of the nb-hyphen to Ariel. `foo<span style="font-family:Ariel>-</span>bar`

Answer (score 0):

Have you fixed the problem? Could you use

```
&ndash;
```

As a substitute?

Comment: Unfortunately, that allows for line breaking if the word you're trying to NOT have break appears near the end of a line. The non-breaking hyphen resolves that by not breaking.